# python extract ip-addresse cidre/-ranges into individual ip-addresses

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip-address, cidr

I am new in python. I would like to scan ip-addresses in python and for that I want to read a file with ip-addresses in different notation like cidr or ranges and the script should extract the ip cidr/ranges into individual ip-addresses.

```
file_in = open("test.txt", "r")
file_out = open("ip-test2.txt","w")
i = 1
for line in file_in:
    #take the line and look if that is a individual ip , if not make block of ip-    
addresses and write them into a new file_out
    file_out.write(str(i) + ": " + line)
    i = i + 1
file_out.close()
file_in.close()
```

Any idea how? or which tool I could use for that?

Comment: Regex sounds like the tool you need. Maybe...

A sample of the input file and what kind of output you want would be helpful though.

Comment: Can you give us a couple of examples of the file? The netaddr package is very widely used.

Comment: @lanhance an example _192.168.132.197/30 192.168.132.123-125 192.0.2.0_ and in the output_file I want to have _192.168.132.197 192.168.132.198 192.168.132.123 192.168.132.124 192.168.132.125 192.0.2.0_ So I get all ips individual

Comment: @Ben thanks :) netaddr works great. there are not some many functions I wish for ranges, but I think I can change ranges into individual ips manual.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that the [python-iptools](https://github.com/bd808/python-iptools) package will do what you're looking for. Basically like so:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file_in:
    ips_and_ranges = IpRangeList(file_in.readlines())

with open("ip-test2.txt","w") as file_out:
    for ip in ips_and_ranges:
        file_out.write(ip)
```

Assuming that file_in is a reasonable size, otherwise you might need to read it in chunks.

UPDATE: My initial code needed a "splat" to unpack the list into args, and also to remove newlines (thus, "basically" :P). Also, to handle the ranges like "10.1.1.1-255" requires some massaging of the data; iptools supports taking ranges like that as a tuple. Assuming the ranges like that only occur in the last octet, this works:

```
from iptools import IpRangeList

def clean(ip_string):

    ret = ip_string.strip()
    if "-" in ret:
        parts = ret.split("-")
        ret = (parts[0], ret.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + "." + parts[1])

    return ret

with open("test.txt", "r") as file_in:
    in_list = [clean(x) for x in file_in.readlines()]

ips_and_ranges = IpRangeList(*in_list)

with open("ip-test2.txt", "w") as file_out:
    for ip in ips_and_ranges:
        file_out.write(ip)
```

Comment: I geht following exception `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SHA1Scanner.py", line 23, in <module>
    ips_and_ranges = IpRangeList(file_in.readlines())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/iptools/__init__.py", line 410, in __init__
    self.ips = tuple(map(IpRange, args))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/iptools/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    elif ipv4.validate_cidr(start):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/iptools/ipv4.py", line 260, in validate_cidr
    if _CIDR_RE.match(s):
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: It needed a "splat" (*) to unpack the list into arguments for the constructor. See my updated answer.